# Long Polling across multiple views iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I'm making an iOS app. This app will also have a integrated chat in it, our chat server works with long polling. The app has multiple views, ex :

```
Login View -> Main Menu View -> etc. etc.
```

Now my problem is that I want the long polling to continue across all the view controller, so that the app itself is constantly connected to the long polling server, and when the response is received, the response data is processed based on the current view so that appropriate actions can be taken based on the current view.

1. So, I have a really bad idea in mind to go about this: Start Long polling after every view change.

Please help me out. Reply if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: did you hear about singleton concept? or singleton class in objective c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of Singleton class
1. Create Singleton class
2. Start your session of long polling in Appdelegate AppDidbecomeActive function
then you can use it in every class and can reset it as well without extra headache.
3. and close your long polling in Appdelegate AppDidEnterintoBackground if you want to close 
it as per your requirements.
4. close it in appwillterminate.
Hope that will help you.

Comment: Shucks!! why didn't I think of it before!...thanks a lot. I have never have programmed singleton classes in obj-c, you have a any good tutorial on it? Time to hit google. Thanks

Comment: OK, so I read about singleton classes in iOS, so I am thinking of sending notification through notification center and registering a observer in each view controller, when the response arrives in the singleton class. Am I going in the right direction?? Thanks a again!!

Comment: if you are registering your observers in each view controller, just take care of your post notification, and make sure you are not missing it, and you know very well what are your requirements, if your application is not affecting by missing Post notification, then you don't need to take extra precautions.